pd-mapper: failed to open remoteproc class: No such file or directory
bt92200@BTRPI-5:~$ journalctl -u pd-mapper.service --since 2024-05-02T12:00:00
May 02 17:14:05 BTRPI-5 systemd[1]: Started pd-mapper.service - Qualcomm PD mapper service.
May 02 17:14:05 BTRPI-5 pd-mapper[1156]: pd-mapper: failed to open remoteproc class: No such file or directory
May 02 17:14:05 BTRPI-5 pd-mapper[1156]: no pd maps available
May 02 17:14:05 BTRPI-5 systemd[1]: pd-mapper.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 02 17:14:05 BTRPI-5 systemd[1]: pd-mapper.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 02 17:14:05 BTRPI-5 systemd[1]: pd-mapper.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
May 02 17:14:05 BTRPI-5 systemd[1]: Started pd-mapper.service - Qualcomm PD mapper service.
May 02 17:14:05 BTRPI-5 pd-mapper[1202]: pd-mapper: failed to open remoteproc class: No such file or directory
May 02 17:14:05 BTRPI-5 pd-mapper[1202]: no pd maps available
May 02 17:14:05 BTRPI-5 systemd[1]: pd-mapper.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 02 17:14:05 BTRPI-5 systemd[1]: pd-mapper.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 02 17:14:05 BTRPI-5 systemd[1]: pd-mapper.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
May 02 17:14:05 BTRPI-5 systemd[1]: Started pd-mapper.service - Qualcomm PD mapper service.
May 02 17:14:05 BTRPI-5 pd-mapper[1249]: pd-mapper: failed to open remoteproc class: No such file or directory
May 02 17:14:05 BTRPI-5 pd-mapper[1249]: no pd maps available
May 02 17:14:05 BTRPI-5 systemd[1]: pd-mapper.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 02 17:14:05 BTRPI-5 systemd[1]: pd-mapper.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 02 17:14:05 BTRPI-5 systemd[1]: pd-mapper.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
May 02 17:14:05 BTRPI-5 systemd[1]: Started pd-mapper.service - Qualcomm PD mapper service.
May 02 17:14:05 BTRPI-5 pd-mapper[1264]: pd-mapper: failed to open remoteproc class: No such file or directory
May 02 17:14:05 BTRPI-5 pd-mapper[1264]: no pd maps available
May 02 17:14:05 BTRPI-5 systemd[1]: pd-mapper.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 02 17:14:05 BTRPI-5 systemd[1]: pd-mapper.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 02 17:14:05 BTRPI-5 systemd[1]: pd-mapper.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.
May 02 17:14:05 BTRPI-5 systemd[1]: Started pd-mapper.service - Qualcomm PD mapper service.
May 02 17:14:05 BTRPI-5 pd-mapper[1283]: pd-mapper: failed to open remoteproc class: No such file or directory
May 02 17:14:05 BTRPI-5 pd-mapper[1283]: no pd maps available
May 02 17:14:05 BTRPI-5 systemd[1]: pd-mapper.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 02 17:14:05 BTRPI-5 systemd[1]: pd-mapper.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 02 17:14:06 BTRPI-5 systemd[1]: pd-mapper.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
May 02 17:14:06 BTRPI-5 systemd[1]: pd-mapper.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
May 02 17:14:06 BTRPI-5 systemd[1]: pd-mapper.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 02 17:14:06 BTRPI-5 systemd[1]: Failed to start pd-mapper.service - Qualcomm PD mapper service.
-- Boot 2b01ed4128ac4182a8ac47b59272b863 --
May 02 17:46:04 BTRPI-5 systemd[1]: Started pd-mapper.service - Qualcomm PD mapper service.
May 02 17:46:04 BTRPI-5 pd-mapper[1150]: pd-mapper: failed to open remoteproc class: No such file or directory


What is your question? It's a service that fails to run while everything seems to be fine. Do sudo systemctl disable pd-mapper.service  and stop worrying for now. No it does not extend you boot time, at least not on my system: systemd-analyze blame -- 144ms pd-mapper.service. Here is the package in Ubuntu: https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/protection-domain-mapper You can look at the change log and the GitHub page. My conclusion so far is this that developers are still working on integrating this service for future improvements. Until that happens, disable it.

Cross posted in https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/pd-mapper-1150-pd-mapper-failed-to-open-remoteproc-class-no-such-file-or-directory/40047 and https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=370114 vote to close since question is of low quality.

Thks Karel !  C U
